# Как подключиться к сети TOR без прокси?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, library, tor

Надо спарсить .onion сайт, но используя curl и другие похожие посты ничего не выходит.

Что я пробовал:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    require("user_agent.php");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Все время ошибка:

Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9050: Connection refused

Пробовал разные варианты, ничего не подходит. Подозреваю что мой хостер заблокировал эту возможность. Есть какие-то библиотеки, которые можно использовать? В каком направлении надо гуглить?

Comment: Ну так вы socks-прокси Tor вообще включили-то?

Comment: @andreymal как это сделать? Я с ним еще не работал. Поэтому и спрашиваю)